# Deriving the interband contribution to the conductivity tensor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, condensed-matter

I'm trying to [derive equation 3.2 in the this document (on page 17)](http://web.mit.edu/course/6/6.732/www/6.732-pt2.pdf) which is the expression for the interband contribution to the conductivity tensor for a semiconductor (equation edited in below).
I've worked through the derivation of the fermi golden rule as a toy example, but am struggling to get from one to the other.  Would anyone have a good textbook or paper reference for how the derivation goes?  I've looked around but come up empty.

Thanks in advance for your time.

[image]